# Plugin plantUML in PyCharm can't find Graphviz

Tags: python, pycharm, graphviz, plantuml

The plugin does not render schemas. The error is shown in the picture.
What is done:

1. Environment variable GRAPHVIZ _DOT = '/usr/bin/dot' added to ./bashrc
   [image]
2. The path /usr/bin/dot is specified in settings in PyCharm
   [image]
3. Checked the performance of graphviz through the output to the file echo 'digraph {a -> b}' | dot -Tsvg> output.svg
4. The diagram is working, drawn on another computer.

Comment: Your point 3. is this tested on the same computer as where pycharm runs? Isn't there a starting `/` missing in the pycharm settings?

Comment: Tested on the same computer. Pycharm settings are not filled (graphviz)

Comment: Did you try to put a `/` before the `usr`? as the error indicates cl;early to it.

Comment: The issue is resolved by checking the box in the Remote rendering settings.